# How to find all records in same month and year ? - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is a table like below picture.

[image]

How can i make a query to do following steps:

**1.** Find all records with `KID=565` then

**2.** find all records with the same year and months that related to `KID=565` after that

**3.** for each record found in stage 2, this equation must be done:

sum of all `PCount * Score`.

For example: `KID = 565` has three records with same year and month `(2015-11-?)` then `sum = (2*1000) + (1*1000) + (4*1000) = 7000` , and ....

Then, the result must be inserted in another table like below picture:

[image]

Comment: What is the version of Sql Server?

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri, sql server 2008

Comment: @Tab Alleman, in your link the date must be entered manually in query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with grouping on year and month:

```
declare @t table(KID int, BuyDate date, Pcount int, Score int)

insert into @t values
(565, '20151120', 2, 1000),
(565, '20151125', 1, 1000),
(565, '20151125', 4, 1000),
(565, '20151220', 8, 1000),
(565, '20151221', 2, 1000),
(1, '20151206', 1, 1000),
(1, '20151219', 1, 1000)


select KID, 
       DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, max(BuyDate)) + 1, 0)) BuyDate,  
       SUM(Pcount * Score) BP,
       MAX(Score) Score
from @t
where KID = 565
group by KID, YEAR(BuyDate), MONTH(BuyDate)
```